# Downloading Steam Error lacking curl, python-apt, and zenity

Tags: steam

```
(Reading database ... 33141 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace steam-launcher 1.0.0.50 (using steam.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement steam-launcher ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
steam-launcher depends on curl; however:
Package curl is not installed.
steam-launcher depends on python-apt; however:
Package python-apt is not installed.
steam-launcher depends on zenity; however:
Package zenity is not installed.
dpkg: error processing steam-launcher (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
steam-launcher
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the missing packages

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install curl python-apt zenity
```

Then try installing Steam again

```
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```